# Drawing a network of nodes in .NET, screen refreshing too slow

Tags: .net, drawing, 2d

I am trying to create a .NET application for a visual representation of a network of nodes. The nodes are Drawing.Rectangle instances that can be dragged with the mouse and connections are made with Graphics.DrawLine. Like below.

[image: network]

To avoid that the rectangles are redrawn leaving an ugly train when they are dragged, I am calling Graphics.Clear on the component and redrawing each rectangle and line at each call of Mouse_Move. But this results in a very ugly, flashing effect as I am thinking that it is being called not to quick enough...

Is there some .NET function or a better method of redrawing this scene so that the refreshing looks smoother?

My Code:

```
    private void NodesPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseButtons.Left == e.Button)
        {

            if (currentlyClickedNode != null)
            {
                surface.Clear(Color.White);
                drawUnselectedNodes();
                drawConnections();

                if (!ClickedNodeGate) // Clicked on the node
                {
                    currentlyClickedNode.setPosition(e.X - QuestNode.NODE_WIDTH / 2, e.Y - QuestNode.NODE_HEIGHT / 2);
                    currentlyClickedNode.drawMe(surface, penl);
                }
                else // clicked on the gate
                {
                    drawingLine = true;
                    currentlyClickedNode.drawMe(surface, penl);
                    DrawingHelper.DrawLine(surface, penl, currentlyClickedNode.getGatePosition(), new Vector2D(e.X, e.Y));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help you may be able to give.

Comment: Have you turned double-buffering on for the form/panel? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx

Comment: Please show the code in how you are currently doing it.

Comment: Added the relevant bit of code. I tried enabling DobuleBuffered on the form with no results

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complex topic, and there are literally thousands of different ways to do this.  You are going to have to learn more about Windows graphics and windowing subsystems.  You might want to start with http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145369079.do